# Does this class-adding slow page rendering?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Can you suggest ways of making this more efficient?  I don't want to repeat this example for all of my tags that need a class added, if there is a better way.

```
$("#menu").find("div:nth-child(2), div:nth-child(3), div:nth-child(4), div:nth-child(5), div:nth-child(6), div:nth-child(7)").addClass("menuDivs");
```

Comment: Are there divs after the 7th that you don't want the class added to?

Comment: And is there a reason the class isn't already in the HTML?

Comment: there is a DIV before the 2nd child. If I add the classes in the HTML I have to write the class on every DIV which just seems ineffective.

Comment: So why not select `#menu div:nth-child(n-1)`?

Comment: didn't know about it? how does it work exactly?

Comment: Ahh.  It wasn't quite right.  (Hadn't played with `nth-child` in a while.)  `#menu div:nth-child(n+2)`  will do it, though.  Basically, for any non-negative integer `n`, it will select the element whose index is `n+2`.  So it'll pick elements 0+2, 1+2 (3), 2+2 (4), etc.    ([Example fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/a_different_name/cubPL/1/))

Comment: You might also be able to say `#menu div:not(:first-child)` (or maybe better, `#menu div:not(.someClassName)` and set that class name on the elements you *don't* want to select).

Comment: very helpful actually, already solved it with slice(1,7) but your answer gives additional options for future problems. Thanks :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's slow for the following reasons:

- You're using [`find()`](https://api.jquery.com/find/) which is a descendant lookup. jQuery will look for all descendants under an element and see if it's a match. If the DOM under that element is huge... you get the picture.
- Additionally, you aren't really specific here. You just give it `div`, which makes it all the more so generic. There could be lots of `<div>` under that element.

What you can do:

- If these elements you have are just children of `#menu`, then use [`children()`](https://api.jquery.com/children/) which is just  searches one level down.
- If the set you have contains the elements you want plus siblings, and they are in order, then you can do [`slice()`](https://api.jquery.com/slice/) instead. Slice is zero-indexed by the way.

  ```
  $('#menu').children('div').slice(1,6).addClass("menuDivs");
  ```

[Here's a demo](http://jsbin.com/lojideka/2/edit)

Answer (score 0):

This actually could be solved using just HTML and CSS. Ditch the DIVs:

```
<div id="menu">
    <ul>
        <li><a href="...">...</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Now your CSS can be much cleaner, and you don't need to use JavaScript to add CSS class names:

```
#menu ul {
    list-style-type: none;
    ...
}
#menu ul>li { ... }
```

If you require JavaScript behavior, the greater diversity of HTML tags can be a benefit here as well:

```
$("#menu").on("click", "li", function(event) { ... });
```